# What causes the Python error in running the flask example?

Tags: python, windows, flask

When I run my Python/Flask script, it throws this error:
`OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
C:\flask_codigofacilito>python hola_mundo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hola_mundo.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.run()#star the server in the port 5000
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 708, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 670, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 564, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 476, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 440, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 454, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

What is the issue and what can I do to fix it?

Run on Windows 10

CODE:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)#new instance, 
app.run()#star the server in the port 5000
```

Comment: Please post the text, not a picture.

Comment: This is the text that shows cmd when running an example in flask

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Windows 7? Please also include your code.

Comment: @ThomasGerot run on windows 10

Comment: Is the port 5000 free? Something else could be using it.

Comment: Since it looks like you're running as administrator, this might be getting blocked via firewall or anti-virus as per https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_8/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way/4a955300-4cc6-4b2f-b426-6d6f07e4eddc?auth=1

Comment: @Scovetta Disable firewall and antivirus, continue the same error running as administrator

Comment: As per @hjpotter92, run `netstat -an` from a command or powershell prompt and see if there's anything listening on port 5000.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks, if it is taking up a windows process port 5000, change port in code by port 8080
If __name__ == "__main__":
     App.run (host = '127.0.0.1', port = 8080, debug = True)